# Postgres DB upload error "No server supplied!"

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

So, I have to import a database in postgres and I get the following error: "No server supplied!"
I searched a bit and I understood that this is because of the PHP file size limit, post size or memory size.
I'm using a LAMP installation on Linux Ubuntu and I've edited the php.ini file from lampstack/php/etc
I've tried everything I've found until now, most people claiming to solve the problem but apparently not mine.
The settings now are these:

```
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
post_max_size = 5000M
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 2G
```

I tried changing anything people talked about, yes I did restart LAMP, the browser, even the computer, I've cleared the cache, nothing...
Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Update: The error log looks like this:
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 84394850 bytes exceeds the limit of 83886080 bytes in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost:8080/phppgadmin/redirect.php?subject=database&server=localhost%3A5432%3Aallow&database=ss_dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> POST Content-Length of 84394850 bytes exceeds the limit of 83886080

83886080 byes = 8Mb

There's a mismatch between what your error says the limit is and what you think your configuration says it is.

You've stated your configuration says `5000M`.  It is possible you have the wrong `php.ini` file.

Try searching for another one:

```
grep -r post_max_size /etc/php5
```

For me this produces:

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:post_max_size = 1024M
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.ucf-dist:post_max_size = 8M
grep: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.old: Permission denied
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini:post_max_size = 8M
```

Notice that on my system there are a few files called `php.ini`.  You are looking for one with `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize` set to `8M`

Answer (score 0):

Error : No server supplied

Steps:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Just change your php.ini (xampp/php/php.ini) file:

```
memory_limit = 1000M
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
```

And, don't forget to restart Apache Module from XAMPP Control Panel

```
sudo service apache2 restart.
```

Comment: Not working for me. Still getting the error ! Strange, I'm getting this error when editing a row. Should I increase the limits? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Late answer, for those who stumble on this through a search).

2 things...

- the error lists 8M as the configured maximum: You probably edited the wrong configuration file. I often use grep -r keyword /etc to find the config file I'm looking for. In this case I expect you to find two config files.
- 5000M is about 5Gigabytes. If someone along the way uses a 32-bit integer, that will be equivalent to 1Gb. That would still allow you to upload the file you have, but in general "too much" can hurt. I would've set the limit to 16M (well above your expected filesize) or even 64M. Much larger becomes impractical anyway.